fail to connect to host when attempting to spin up metabase using mysql database in docker
I am trying to spin up a simple stack in my github codespace instance. I have a simple docker-compose.yml  that looks like the following.
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: metabase
      MYSQL_USER: metabase_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: metabase_password
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

  metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      MB_DB_TYPE: mysql
      MB_DB_DBNAME: metabase
      MB_DB_PORT: 3306
      MB_DB_USER: metabase_user
      MB_DB_PASS: metabase_password
      MB_DB_HOST: mysql
      MB_DB_CONNECTION_URI: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false

volumes:
  mysql_data:



Despite adding the line `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false. as suggested by the following SO post , i keep getting the following error:
2024-05-21 01:42:03,759 INFO db.setup :: Verifying mysql Database Connection ...
2024-05-21 01:42:33,869 ERROR metabase.core :: Metabase Initialization FAILED
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Unable to connect to Metabase mysql DB. {}
        at metabase.db.setup$verify_db_connection$fn__51167.invoke(setup.clj:113)
        at metabase.db.setup$verify_db_connection.invokeStatic(setup.clj:111)
        at metabase.db.setup$verify_db_connection.invoke(setup.clj:103)
        at metabase.db.setup$setup_db_BANG_$fn__51187$fn__51188.invoke(setup.clj:163)
        at metabase.util.jvm$do_with_us_locale.invokeStatic(jvm.clj:239)
        at metabase.util.jvm$do_with_us_locale.invoke(jvm.clj:225)
        at metabase.db.setup$setup_db_BANG_$fn__51187.invoke(setup.clj:160)
        at metabase.db.setup$setup_db_BANG_.invokeStatic(setup.clj:159)
        at metabase.db.setup$setup_db_BANG_.invoke(setup.clj:153)
        at metabase.db$setup_db_BANG_$fn__51207.invoke(db.clj:69)
        at metabase.db$setup_db_BANG_.invokeStatic(db.clj:64)
        at metabase.db$setup_db_BANG_.invoke(db.clj:55)
        at metabase.core$init_BANG__STAR_.invokeStatic(core.clj:116)
        at metabase.core$init_BANG__STAR_.invoke(core.clj:101)
        at metabase.core$init_BANG_.invokeStatic(core.clj:159)
        at metabase.core$init_BANG_.invoke(core.clj:154)
        at metabase.core$start_normally.invokeStatic(core.clj:171)
        at metabase.core$start_normally.invoke(core.clj:165)
        at metabase.core$entrypoint.invokeStatic(core.clj:204)
        at metabase.core$entrypoint.doInvoke(core.clj:198)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:662)
        at metabase.bootstrap$_main.invokeStatic(bootstrap.clj:31)
        at metabase.bootstrap$_main.doInvoke(bootstrap.clj:28)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at metabase.bootstrap.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:692)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:372)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$get_connection.invoke(jdbc.clj:274)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1111)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invoke(jdbc.clj:1093)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1182)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invoke(jdbc.clj:1144)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1160)
        at clojure.java.jdbc$query.invoke(jdbc.clj:1144)
        at metabase.driver.sql_jdbc.connection$can_connect_with_spec_QMARK_.invokeStatic(connection.clj:331)
        at metabase.driver.sql_jdbc.connection$can_connect_with_spec_QMARK_.invoke(connection.clj:328)
        at metabase.db.setup$verify_db_connection$fn__51167.invoke(setup.clj:111)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1507)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:197)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1395)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at metabase.db.data_source.DataSource.getConnection(data_source.clj:33)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:213)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1176)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1163)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1908)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:73)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:188)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:265)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:537)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1390)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createSocket(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:257)
        ... 15 more
2024-05-21 01:42:33,883 INFO metabase.core :: Metabase Shutting Down ...
2024-05-21 01:42:33,883 INFO metabase.server :: Shutting Down Embedded Jetty Webserver
2024-05-21 01:42:33,898 WARN db.liquibase :: ()
2024-05-21 01:42:33,899 INFO metabase.core :: Metabase Shutdown COMPLETE
Warning: environ value jdk-11.0.23+9 for key :java-version has been overwritten with 11.0.23
2024-05-21 01:42:41,540 INFO metabase.util :: Maximum memory available to JVM: 1.9 GB

Please advice on what i should do to resolve this error

Mysql does not run on the same container as your metabase, so connecting to localhost from metabase cannot possibly succeed.

Replace localhost by mysql in your connection string. You need to use service name to connect between containers.

You don't need to define MB_DB_CONNECTION_URI.
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: metabase
      MYSQL_USER: metabase_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: metabase_password
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-umetabase_user", "-pmetabase_password"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 30

  metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      MB_DB_TYPE: mysql
      MB_DB_DBNAME: metabase
      MB_DB_PORT: 3306
      MB_DB_USER: metabase_user
      MB_DB_PASS: metabase_password
      MB_DB_HOST: mysql
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

The health check ensures that the database is ready to accept connections before Metabase is started.
